# How can I do a world wide search on mapkit and not just in certain parameters

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to do a world wide search for countries and cities.

[this is my location search table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pd3w.png)

[this is my main VC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXY9a.png)

Comment: Please paste code as code, as that makes it a lot easier to answer

Comment: Hey Cam J, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [ask], then come back and edit your question accordingly. As-is, people will have a very hard time helping you and will most likely just downvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

For worldwide searches, you can use [`CLGeocoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder). For example:

```
var strings: [String]?
```

And

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return strings?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = strings![indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func performSearch(for string: String) {
        strings = nil
        tableView.reloadData()

        if geocoder.isGeocoding { geocoder.cancelGeocode() }

        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(string) { placemarks, error in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, error == nil, placemarks.count > 0 else {
                print("none found")
                return
            }

            self.strings = placemarks.map {
                [$0.subLocality, $0.locality, $0.administrativeArea, $0.country]
                    .flatMap { $0 }
                    .joined(separator: ", ")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The `CLGeocoder` often returns a single placemark, what it apparently considers the best match. (E.g. try searching for "Springfield" and compare to a [more exhaustive list of matches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springfield).) If you want a more matches, you might have to consider third party APIs such as Google Maps/Places.

---

For example, you can use [Google Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start). If you wanted to search with Google:

```
func performGoogleSearch(for string: String) {
    strings = nil
    tableView.reloadData()

    var components = URLComponents(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json")!
    let key = URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "...") // use your key
    let address = URLQueryItem(name: "address", value: string)
    components.queryItems = [key, address]

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: components.url!) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, error == nil else {
            print(String(describing: response))
            print(String(describing: error))
            return
        }

        guard let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("not JSON format expected")
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Not string?!?")
            return
        }

        guard let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
            let status = json["status"] as? String,
            status == "OK" else {
                print("no results")
                print(String(describing: json))
                return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.strings = results.flatMap { $0["formatted_address"] as? String }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

This can show ~6 different matches.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I will have to look into adding a third party I'm a new at this and didn't know that was a option